# Can we find the area of a circle using integration but not switching to polar coordinate?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, definite-integrals

I am still a novice in calculus but I still tried finding the area of a circle using integration.It was comparatively very easy but only when we switched to polar coordinate, We switch to polar coordinate because it is very much easier to solve integral from there but can we solve it without switching to polar coordinate and if so how will we get the *π* in the formula? (Same goes for volume of a sphere, a cylinder etc, without switching the coordinate system?)
I've tried solving it myself but I still couldn't get the right answer

Comment: Well, is a trig sub allowed on integrating the function $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly easy if you know the formula for integrating $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$, which can be derived by integration by parts. Since the circle is symmetric about x-axis,therfore we have area$=2\int_{-r}^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}dx=2[\frac{x\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}{2}+\frac{r^2}{2}\arcsin{\frac{x}{r}}]_{-r}^r=\frac{\pi r^2}{2}-(-\frac{\pi r^2}{2})=\pi r^2$